# Do I need to disable OpenMP on a 1 core machine explicitly?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, openmp

I parallelized some C++ code with OpenMP.
But what if my program will work on a 1 core machine?

Do I need disable usage threading at runtime:

1. Checks cores
2. If cores > 1 use OpenMP
3. Else ignore OpenMP devectives

If yes, does OpenMP have a special directive for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is function called:

```
omp_get_num_procs()
```

that will let you know how many processors are available for OpenMP to work on. Then there are many ways to disable OpenMP. From your code you can run:

```
omp_set_num_threads(1)
```

Just remember that even on single core you can get some boost with OpenMP. It only depends on the specificity of your case.

Comment: Remember too that OpenMP can impose an unwanted overhead on the execution time of a program running on only one thread.

Comment: That's true. If you don't want to use it thenthe best way would be to disable OpenMP at compilation time. I simply focsed on 'at runtime' case ;)

Comment: Yes, i think that on 1 core machine threading can impose overhead and it can be good does not use threading at all . But i cannot disable it in compile time because i dont know environment of my clients: it can be servers with many cores or simple machine with one core(for example for tests my software purposes)

Comment: @MateuszKleinert, omp_set_num_threads(1) just runs omp in one thread? May be there is something like #pragma omp parallel if (cores > 1) . and if that condition is not true that code executed sequentially

Comment: @MateuszKleinert answered on my question: as i understand if i set 1 thread with omp_set_num_threads(1) then will be executed master thread that is extra threads will not be created! But may be open mp itself can give some little overhead

Comment: Yes, it only restricts number of threads to one. There is such a construction: `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)  if (scalar expression)`

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't *need* to disable OpenMP or threading for running on one core; and for situations where you might want to, you're probably better off explicitly re-compiling without OpenMP, although for complex parallelizations there are other measures, mentioned in the comments, that you can take as well.

When running on a single core or even hardware thread, even if you change nothing - not even the number of threads your code launches - correct, deadlock-free threading code should still run correctly, as the operating system schedules the various threads on the core.

Now, that context switching between threads is costly overhead.  Typical OpenMP code, which is compute-bound and relies on [work sharing constructs](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#WorkSharing) to assign work between threads, treats the number of threads as a parameter and launches as many threads as you have cores or hardware threads available.  For such code, where you are just using constructs like

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (i=0; i<N; i++) 
   data[i] = expensive_function(i)
```

then running on one core will likely only use one thread, or you can explicitly set the number of threads to be one using the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable.  If OpenMP is to use only one thread and the computation is time-consuming enough, the overhead from the threading library in the above loop is negligible.  In this case, there's really no disabling of OpenMP necessary; you're just running on one thread.  You can also set the number of threads within the program using `omp_set_num_threads()`, but best practice is normally to do this at runtime.

*However*, there's a downside.  Compiling with OpenMP disables certain optimizations.  For instance, because the work decomposition is done at runtime, even loops with compiled-in trip count limits may not be able to, say, be unrolled or vectorized as effectively  because it isn't known how many trips through the loop each thread will take.  In that case, if you know that your code will be run on a single core, it may be worth doing the compilation without OpenMP enabled as well, and using that binary for single-core runs.  You can also use this approach to test to see if the difference in optimizations matters, running the OpenMP-enabled version with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` and comparing the timing to that of serial binary.

Of course, if your threading is more complex than using simple work sharing constructs, then it starts being harder to make generalizations.  If you have assumptions built into your code about how many threads are present - maybe you have an explicit producer/consumer model for processing work, or a data decomposition hardcoded in, either of which are doable in OpenMP - then it's harder to see how things work.  You may also have parallel regions which are much less work than a big computational loop; in those cases, where overhead even with one thread might be significant, it might be best to use `if` clauses to provide explicit serial paths, e.g.:

```
nThreadMax = imp_get_max_threads();
#pragma omp parallel if (nThreadMax > 1)  
if (omp_in_parallel()) {
    // Parallel code path
} else {
    // Serial code path  
}
```

But now doing compilation without OpenMP becomes more complicated.

Summarizing:

- For big heavy computation work, which is what OpenMP is typically used for, it probably doesn't matter; use OMP_NUM_THREADS=1

  - You can test if it *does* matter, with overhead and disabled optimizations, by compiling without OpenMP and comparing the serial runtime to the one-thread OpenMP runtime
- For more complicated threading cases, it's hard to say much in general; it depends.